# Volley reporting HTTP response code 408, but Fiddler shows 200

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley

I'm using Volley in a project here and I'm randomly seeing requests requests come back with a response code of **408**

```
E/Volley﹕ [3103] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 408 for ...
```

However, I'm proxying through Fiddler to see what's actually going on, and Fiddler reports the requests as **200**, AKA: fine and dandy.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I've experienced it on a range of devices from 2.x all the way up to 4.4

Comment: Have you figured out the cause of this? I'm getting the exact ame behavior too

Comment: It appears to be Fiddler it's self. I tracked it down deep into Volley, and Volley doesn't appear to be doing anything wrong. It really is getting 408. And when I don't proxy to Fiddler, I never get it. Maybe a bug in Fiddler?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this ? I often get a 408 on the very first request I make after launching the app, but the others always get through after that... Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just trace it with wireshark (install your app on genymotion emulator on PC) and compare results for both request and response..